# Firebase saying arrayUnion was called with invalid data

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im getting an error with firebase because im trying to update two values when I press handleSelect. Only issue is that the first updateDoc works fine as I'm trying to add an array into the "user" specific userChats database, but when I try to do the opposite and add the user array to the "chat" database, it fails.

```
const handleSelect = async(chat) =>{
    const docRef = doc(db, 'users', user?.uid)
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef)

    const addRef = doc(db, 'userChats', user?.uid)
    await updateDoc(addRef, {
      userChats: arrayUnion(chat)
    })

    const addRecieverRef = doc(db, 'userChats', chat?.uid)
    await updateDoc(addRecieverRef, {
      userChats: arrayUnion(user)
    })
    console.log(chat.uid)
    
    const concatUID = user.uid > chat.uid ? user.uid + chat.uid : chat.uid + user.uid;
    if(!docSnap.exists() && user.uid!=chat.uid){
      await setDoc(doc(db, 'messages', concatUID), {
        messages: [],
      })
    }
    else{
      dispatch({type: 'CHANGE_USER', payload: chat})
      console.log(chat)
    }

  }
```

Error

```
Chats.js:53 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: 
Function arrayUnion() called with invalid data. 
Unsupported field value: a custom UserImpl object (found in document userChats/lJ4u4PqWynXAPthz3FVgYaQQ0Do1)
```

I already checked and all the reference values are correct, and both "user" and "chat" are plain objects

Answer (score 0):

Firestore can only store values of the types indicated in its documentation on [data types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types). The `UserImpl` object that you are trying to store is not of a supported type, which is what the error message indicates.

If the `user` object comes from Firebase Authentication, you can [call `toJSON()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user.md#usertojson) on it to get a JSON serialization of its data.